# Deduce return type of a function template from argument types (not from arguments)

Tags: c++11, templates, decltype

I am aware of the very straightforward usage of `decltype`, as in

```
template<typename T, typename F>
auto myfunc(T elem, F func) -> decltype(func(elem)) 
{
    return func(elem);
}
```

I would like to know whether return type of a function can be deduced without reference to the function arguments, but instead to the argument type, i.e. something akin to `decltype(func, T)`?

I understand that in this case one is a type and the other is an object, but what I'm trying to do seems to be very natural. Yet I failed to find a simple way of expressing what I want. Any help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is exactly what [`std::declval`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) is for:

```
template<typename T, typename F>
auto myfunc(T elem, F func) -> decltype(func(std::declval<T>())) 
{
    return func(elem);
}
```

But since you do have an object of that type already, why bother?

Comment: My intention was to pass a container and use `::value_type` to determine the return type of my function, which takes the first element (e.g.) as an argument. 
Maybe something like `decltype(func(declval<typename CType::value_type>)))` where `CType` the type of the container object (provided is has the `::value_type` member). Doesn't work that easily, though.

Comment: @Jersey add `std::declval`'s parentheses (it's a function) and you should be good to go.

Comment: You were right, indeed - thank you so much. It's funny how such lesser inaccuracies (in human terms) spin around the semantics. And compilers are picky :p